# Reduce/Inject Operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, operators

I'm testing out the reduce/inject method and ruby and came across a command with unexpected results.

`(1..2).reduce(:<<)` produces `#=> 4`

I believe I understand what `reduce` and `inject` do but I'm not understanding the `<<` operator.

Comment: So, is your question about `reduce` or `<<`? Make up your mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<<` operator is the Binary Left Shift Operator. It will shift the bits in the binary representation of the number the amount of places you specify.

So `1 << 2` will shift all the bits of `1` left by `2` positions.

In your example code, `1` will be shifted `2` positions to the left, which is the binary representation of `4`, which is the result.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is `Binary Left Shift Operator`. The left operands value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

e.g.

```
10 << 2 #=> 40.
```

10 binary representation is `0000 1010` will be shifted to left by 2 bits and the result will be `0010 1000` which is 40

Comment: `10 << 2` is 40, not 36. 10 is `1010`.